# How can i Update Cloud firestore document Field with the help DocumentID?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here i am trying to update the exit-time of the user with the help of documentID(String keyId). The updation is done when the user add the DOCUMENTID or keyId in given INPUTFIELD and the  Exit-time:Value(get updated).The data in the cloud_database is updating in the way like(KeyId(KzlWLHJc0di6QziewVV7) => InputField => Update done in the cloud_database).

```
1st Code:(The below code working & updating properly in database)

String KeyId;
QuerySnapshot qs = await Firestore.instance.collection('student entry').getDocuments();
qs.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot snap) async {
  if(snap.documentID == keyId )  {
    DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection(
        'student entry').document(keyId);
    documentReference.updateData({
        'Exit-time': date,

    });
```

But now i have add authentication for every user.The database storing  the data individually for every user.Now i dont know what Else modification can i do in the 2nd code to have working process like Above code.

```
  2nd code:

  String keyId;
  CollectionReference vaultCollection =  Firestore.instance.collection('student entry').document(uid).collection('vault');         //Where should i add keyId new code
 DocumentReference doc=vaultCollection.document();
 doc.updateData({

   'Exit-time': date,


  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the `Document ID` where you want to update the data. You can use the `setData` function with  `merge: true`.You don't have to fetch the data to update it.

From your example,`KeyId` is the `Document ID` where you want to update the data.

**1st Code**

```
DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection('student entry').document(keyId);
documentReference.setData({'Exit-time': date},merge:true);
```

**2nd Code**

Now since you are storing the data in `Sub-Collection`.Only the document reference will be updated.

```
DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection('student entry').document(uid).collection('vault').document(keyId);
documentReference.setData({'Exit-time': date},merge:true);
```

Hope this helps.